# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/xml/JDom2Driver

Tags: java, xml, maven

My XStream2 class:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.JDom2Driver;
    public class XStream2 extends XStream {
            /**
             * @param domDriver
             */
            public XStream2(DomDriver domDriver) {
                super(domDriver);
            }

            /**
             * @param jDomDriver
             */
            public XStream2(JDom2Driver jDomDriver) {
                super(jDomDriver);
            }

            /**
             * 
             */
            public XStream2() {
                super();
            }
    }
```

My pom.xml has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
  <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to create an object of type XStream2:

```
XStream2 xstream = new XStream2(new JDom2Driver());
```

I get the below error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/xml/JDom2Driver

Please help me know what I am missing?

Comment: Choose your version of `JDom2Driver` that you're using and add the corresponding `Maven` repository link to your `pom.xml`. Link [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom2)